# samsung smart tv sdk 4.1 application not working on sdk 5.1

Tags: html, jsp, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

I have made an application on Samsung Smart TV SDK 4.1, but that application is not working on Samsung Smart TV SDK 5.1.

Can any one help me with remote working in sdk 5.1

I have tried some demo apps from [samsungdforum](http://www.samsungdforum.com/) but its not helping me.

Code:
The code is:

**Main.js**

```
var widgetAPI = new Common.API.Widget();
var tvKey = new Common.API.TVKeyValue();

var current_selected_index=0;
var menu_count=5;

var Main =
{

};

Main.onLoad = function()
{
    // Enable key event processing
    this.enableKeys();
    widgetAPI.sendReadyEvent();
};

Main.onUnload = function()
{

};

Main.enableKeys = function()
{
    document.getElementById("menu").focus();
    $('.menu').eq(current_selected_index).addClass('selected');
    $('.menu a').eq(current_selected_index).focus();
};

Main.keyDown = function()
{
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;
    alert("Key pressed: " + keyCode);

    switch(keyCode)
    {
      case tvKey.KEY_UP:
        alert("UP");
        $('.menu').eq(current_selected_index).removeClass("selected");
        if(current_selected_index==0){
            current_selected_index=3;
        }
        else{
            current_selected_index--;
        }
        $('.menu').eq(current_selected_index).addClass("selected");
        break;
       case tvKey.KEY_DOWN:
            alert("DOWN");
            $('.menu').eq(current_selected_index).removeClass("selected");
            if(current_selected_index==3){
                current_selected_index=0;
            }
            else{
                current_selected_index--;
            }
            $('.menu').eq(current_selected_index).addClass("selected");
       break;   
       case tvKey.KEY_LEFT:
            alert("LEFT");
            $('.menu').eq(current_selected_index).removeClass("selected");
            if(current_selected_index==0){
                current_selected_index=4;
            }
            else{
                current_selected_index--;
            }
            $('.menu').eq(current_selected_index).addClass("selected");
            $('.menu a').eq(current_selected_index).focus();
            break;
        case tvKey.KEY_RIGHT:
            alert("RIGHT");
            $('.menu').eq(current_selected_index).removeClass("selected");
            if(current_selected_index==4){
                current_selected_index=0;
            }
            else{
                current_selected_index++;
            }
            $('.menu').eq(current_selected_index).addClass("selected");
            $('.menu a').eq(current_selected_index).focus();
            break;
        case tvKey.KEY_ENTER:



            var $j;
            $('#display').html($('.menu a').eq(current_selected_index).html());
            $j=$('.menu a').eq(current_selected_index).html();
            window.location=$j+".html";
            alert($(this).html());
            break;

        case tvKey.KEY_PANEL_ENTER:
            $('#display').html($('.menu a').eq(current_selected_index).html());
            alert($(this).html());
            break;
        default:
            alert("Unhandled key");
            break;
    }
};

Main.mouseclick=function()
{
    $('#display').html($('.menu a').eq(current_selected_index).html());
    window.location="hyderabad.html";
}; 

**Main.css**

*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}

body
{
    width: 960px;
    height: 540px;
}

#container
    {
    width:800px;
    height:400px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-250px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-150px;
    border:1pxsolid#fff;
    border-radius:5px;

    }

.retunbtn
    {
    position:absolute;
    left:80%;
    margin-left:-150px;
    top:80%;
    margin-top:-180px;
    border:1pxsolid#fff;
    border-radius:5px;
    }

    .menu
    {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:6em;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom,rgb(135,135,135) 7%, rgb(184,184,184) 54%);
    border-radius:5px;

    }

    .menu a{
    color:#8B0000;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;

    }   

    #display{
    clear:both;
    width:400px;
    height:100px;
    margin-left:50px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:50px;
    border:1pxsolid#fff;
    border-radius:5px;
    text-align:center;
    color:blue;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-weight:3em;

    }

    .selected
    {
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom,rgb(135,135,135)7%,rgb(184,184,184)54%);
    color:black;
    }

    #content{
    color:#800000;
    font:bold;
    align-text:center;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-250px;
    top:30%;
    margin-top:-150px;

    }

    .menu1 {
      float:left;
      width:20%;
      height:100%;
    }
    .mainContent {
      float:left;
      width:80%;
      height:100%;
    }

    a:link, a:visited {
    color: (internal value);
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: auto;
}

a:link:active, a:visited:active {
    color: (internal value);
} 


**index.html**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>tourism</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app/javascript/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  
        <!-- TODO : Common API -->
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/Widget.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/TVKeyValue.js"></script>
        <!-- TODO : Javascript code -->
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="app/javascript/Main.js"></script>
        <!-- TODO : Style sheets code -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/stylesheets/Main.css" type="text/css">
        <!-- TODO: Plugins -->
    </head>
    <body onload="Main.onLoad();" onunload="Main.onUnload();">
        <!-- Dummy anchor as focus for key events -->
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="menu" onkeydown="Main.keyDown();"></a>
        <div id="content">
        <h1>INDIA TOURISM APPLICATION</h1>

        </div>

         <div id="container">
             <div class="menu">


             <a href="javascript.void(0);" onkeydown="Main.keyDown();" >HYDERABAD</a>

              </div>
              <div class="menu">
             <a href="javascript.void(0);" onkeydown="Main.keyDown();">Delhi</a>
              </div>
              <div class="menu">

             <a href="javascript.void(0);" onkeydown="Main.keyDown();">Jaipur</a>
             </div>

              <div class="menu">

             <a href="javascript.void(0);" onkeydown="Main.keyDown();">Jaipurs</a>
             </div>

              <div class="menu">

             <a href="javascript.void(0);" onkeydown="Main.keyDown();">Jaipur1</a>
             </div>

         </div> 

    enter code here

        <img src="images/wallpaper.jpg" style="width:960px;height:540px" >
        <!-- TODO: your code here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you show the code which works for 4.1  and doesn't do so for 5.1 ?

Comment: The app code is given below in answers

Answer (score 2):

first of all in main.enableKeys function you have to enable the keycodes.

> `var pluginAPI = new Common.API.Plugin();`

```
> pluginAPI.registKey(tvKey.KEY_RETURN);
>     pluginAPI.registKey(tvKey.KEY_EXIT);
```

than try to run application through remote.

Answer (score 0):

```
The code is: 

**Main.js**

var widgetAPI = new Common.API.Widget();
var tvKey = new Common.API.TVKeyValue();

var current_selected_index=0;
var menu_count=5;

var Main =
{

};

Main.onLoad = function()
{
    // Enable key event processing
    this.enableKeys();
    widgetAPI.sendReadyEvent();
};

Main.onUnload = function()
{

};

Main.enableKeys = function()
{
    document.getElementById("menu").focus();
    $('.menu').eq(current_selected_index).addClass('selected');
    $('.menu a').eq(current_selected_index).focus();
};

Main.keyDown = function()
{
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;
    alert("Key pressed: " + keyCode);

    switch(keyCode)
    {
      case tvKey.KEY_UP:
        alert("UP");
        $('.menu').eq(current_selected_index).removeClass("selected");
        if(current_selected_index==0){
            current_selected_index=3;
        }
        else{
            current_selected_index--;
        }
        $('.menu').eq(current_selected_index).addClass("selected");
        break;
       case tvKey.KEY_DOWN:
            alert("DOWN");
            $('.menu').eq(current_selected_index).removeClass("selected");
            if(current_selected_index==3){
                current_selected_index=0;
            }
            else{
                current_selected_index--;
            }
            $('.menu').eq(current_selected_index).addClass("selected");
       break;   
       case tvKey.KEY_LEFT:
            alert("LEFT");
            $('.menu').eq(current_selected_index).removeClass("selected");
            if(current_selected_index==0){
                current_selected_index=4;
            }
            else{
                current_selected_index--;
            }
            $('.menu').eq(current_selected_index).addClass("selected");
            $('.menu a').eq(current_selected_index).focus();
            break;
        case tvKey.KEY_RIGHT:
            alert("RIGHT");
            $('.menu').eq(current_selected_index).removeClass("selected");
            if(current_selected_index==4){
                current_selected_index=0;
            }
            else{
                current_selected_index++;
            }
            $('.menu').eq(current_selected_index).addClass("selected");
            $('.menu a').eq(current_selected_index).focus();
            break;
        case tvKey.KEY_ENTER:



            var $j;
            $('#display').html($('.menu a').eq(current_selected_index).html());
            $j=$('.menu a').eq(current_selected_index).html();
            window.location=$j+".html";
            alert($(this).html());
            break;

        case tvKey.KEY_PANEL_ENTER:
            $('#display').html($('.menu a').eq(current_selected_index).html());
            alert($(this).html());
            break;
        default:
            alert("Unhandled key");
            break;
    }
};

Main.mouseclick=function()
{
    $('#display').html($('.menu a').eq(current_selected_index).html());
    window.location="hyderabad.html";
}; 

**Main.css**

*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}

body
{
    width: 960px;
    height: 540px;
}

#container
    {
    width:800px;
    height:400px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-250px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-150px;
    border:1pxsolid#fff;
    border-radius:5px;

    }

.retunbtn
    {
    position:absolute;
    left:80%;
    margin-left:-150px;
    top:80%;
    margin-top:-180px;
    border:1pxsolid#fff;
    border-radius:5px;
    }

    .menu
    {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:6em;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom,rgb(135,135,135) 7%, rgb(184,184,184) 54%);
    border-radius:5px;

    }

    .menu a{
    color:#8B0000;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;

    }   

    #display{
    clear:both;
    width:400px;
    height:100px;
    margin-left:50px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:50px;
    border:1pxsolid#fff;
    border-radius:5px;
    text-align:center;
    color:blue;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-weight:3em;

    }

    .selected
    {
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom,rgb(135,135,135)7%,rgb(184,184,184)54%);
    color:black;
    }

    #content{
    color:#800000;
    font:bold;
    align-text:center;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-250px;
    top:30%;
    margin-top:-150px;

    }

    .menu1 {
      float:left;
      width:20%;
      height:100%;
    }
    .mainContent {
      float:left;
      width:80%;
      height:100%;
    }

    a:link, a:visited {
    color: (internal value);
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: auto;
}

a:link:active, a:visited:active {
    color: (internal value);
} 


**index.html**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>tourism</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app/javascript/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  
        <!-- TODO : Common API -->
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/Widget.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/TVKeyValue.js"></script>
        <!-- TODO : Javascript code -->
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="app/javascript/Main.js"></script>
        <!-- TODO : Style sheets code -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/stylesheets/Main.css" type="text/css">
        <!-- TODO: Plugins -->
    </head>
    <body onload="Main.onLoad();" onunload="Main.onUnload();">
        <!-- Dummy anchor as focus for key events -->
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="menu" onkeydown="Main.keyDown();"></a>
        <div id="content">
        <h1>INDIA TOURISM APPLICATION</h1>

        </div>

         <div id="container">
             <div class="menu">


             <a href="javascript.void(0);" onkeydown="Main.keyDown();" >HYDERABAD</a>

              </div>
              <div class="menu">
             <a href="javascript.void(0);" onkeydown="Main.keyDown();">Delhi</a>
              </div>
              <div class="menu">

             <a href="javascript.void(0);" onkeydown="Main.keyDown();">Jaipur</a>
             </div>

              <div class="menu">

             <a href="javascript.void(0);" onkeydown="Main.keyDown();">Jaipurs</a>
             </div>

              <div class="menu">

             <a href="javascript.void(0);" onkeydown="Main.keyDown();">Jaipur1</a>
             </div>

         </div> 

    enter code here

        <img src="images/wallpaper.jpg" style="width:960px;height:540px" >
        <!-- TODO: your code here -->
    </body>
</html>
```